# Rails 5 not using bundle from vendor/bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i have a rails5 app ubnuntu 16.04 puma
here is output from puma.stderr.log

```
/home/ashish/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

although this is the result of bundle show command

```
* actioncable (5.1.4)
  * actionmailer (5.1.4)
  * actionpack (5.1.4)
  * actionview (5.1.4)
  * activejob (5.1.4)
  * activemerchant (1.73.0)
  * activemodel (5.1.4)
  * activerecord (5.1.4)
  * activesupport (5.1.4)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0)
  * acts_as_list (0.9.9)
  * addressable (2.5.2)
  * arel (8.0.0)
  * autoprefixer-rails (7.1.6)
  * awesome_nested_set (3.1.3)
  * bcrypt (3.1.11)
  * bindex (0.5.0)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
  * builder (3.2.3)
  * bundler (1.16.0)
  * byebug (9.1.0)
  * camertron-eprun (1.1.1)
  * cancancan (2.0.0)
  * canonical-rails (0.2.1)
  * capybara (2.15.4)
  * carmen (1.0.2)
  * childprocess (0.8.0)
  * cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (1.0.1)
  * climate_control (0.2.0)
  * cocaine (0.5.8)
  * coffee-rails (4.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
  * crass (1.0.2)
  * css_parser (1.6.0)
  * deface (1.2.0)
  * devise (4.3.0)
  * devise-encryptable (0.2.0)
  * erubi (1.7.0)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * ffaker (2.7.0)
  * ffi (1.9.18)
  * friendly_id (5.2.3)
  * globalid (0.4.0)
  * highline (1.6.21)
  * htmlentities (4.3.4)
  * i18n (0.8.6)
  * jbuilder (2.7.0)
  * jquery-rails (4.3.1)
  * jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
  * kaminari (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-core (1.0.1)
  * loofah (2.1.1)
  * mail (2.6.6)
  * method_source (0.9.0)
  * mime-types (3.1)
  * mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
  * mimemagic (0.3.2)
  * mini_mime (0.1.4)
  * mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
  * minitest (5.10.3)
  * monetize (1.7.0)
  * money (6.9.0)
  * multi_json (1.12.2)
  * mysql2 (0.4.9)
  * nio4r (2.1.0)
  * nokogiri (1.8.1)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * paperclip (5.1.0)
  * paranoia (2.3.1)
  * polyamorous (1.3.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.5)
  * premailer (1.11.0)
  * premailer-rails (1.9.7)
  * public_suffix (3.0.0)
  * puma (3.10.0)
  * rabl (0.13.1)
  * rack (2.0.3)
  * rack-test (0.7.0)
  * rails (5.1.4)
  * rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * railties (5.1.4)
  * rainbow (2.2.2)
  * rake (12.1.0)
  * ransack (1.8.4)
  * rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.10)
  * responders (2.4.0)
  * rubyzip (1.2.1)
  * sass (3.5.2)
  * sass-listen (4.0.0)
  * sass-rails (5.0.6)
  * select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
  * selenium-webdriver (3.6.0)
  * spree (3.3.1)
  * spree_api (3.3.1)
  * spree_auth_devise (3.3.1)
  * spree_backend (3.3.1)
  * spree_cmd (3.3.1)
  * spree_core (3.3.1)
  * spree_extension (0.0.5)
  * spree_frontend (3.3.1)
  * spree_frontend_medical_shop (0.0.1.alpha)
  * spree_gateway (3.3.0)
  * spree_product_brands (0.0.1.alpha)
  * spree_related_products (3.3.0)
  * spree_sample (3.3.1)
  * spree_scaffold (3.0.0)
  * spree_slider (3.1.0)
  * sprockets (3.7.1)
  * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
  * state_machines (0.5.0)
  * state_machines-activemodel (0.5.0)
  * state_machines-activerecord (0.5.0)
  * stringex (2.7.1)
  * thor (0.20.0)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * tilt (2.0.8)
  * turbolinks (5.0.1)
  * turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
  * twitter_cldr (4.4.2)
  * tzinfo (1.2.3)
  * uglifier (3.2.0)
  * versioncake (3.3.0)
  * warden (1.2.7)
  * web-console (3.5.1)
  * websocket-driver (0.6.5)
  * websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
  * xpath (2.1.0)
```

my .bundle/config file

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "true"
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

you can easily see that all the required gems are installed.
please tell me why its not using bundle from vendor/bundle

Env
ubuntu 16.04
puma 3
rail 5
ruby 2.33
using rbenv

here is the gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'spree', '3.3.1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'

gem 'spree_slider', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_slider'
gem 'spree_related_products', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_related_products'
gem 'spree_frontend_medical_shop', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_frontend_medical_shop'
gem 'spree_product_brands', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_product_brands'
#gem 'spree_wallet', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_wallet'

#gem 'sprockets-helpers', '~> 1.2.1'
#gem 'vinsol_spree_themes', path: 'E:\Websites\Developing\MedBharat\spree_themes'
group :development do
  gem 'spree_scaffold', path: 'vendor/gems/spree_scaffold'
end
```

some are local gems

Comment: Can you paste your Gemfile?

Comment: hi i pasted the gemfile above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that i developed it on windows and was deploying to ubuntu. So the native gems were not being installed. when i added the required platforms in the gemfile and ran bundle install the app was working fine